# Should a common data pattern be separated into its own sql table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Is there a precedence one way or the other for separating a common subset of multiple tables into its own table with a key for type?

Example:
Hipmunk allows you to search for flights with "trip details" of

```
{
   departure_location: Orlando,
   destination_location: Miami,
   departure_date: 2016-05-05,
   return_date: 2016-05-10
}
```

After making a search there is a recent search tracker and you can save a flight into "my saved flights". Further if you book a flight then there is  presumably a record for that as well. So the following tables would all have "trip details" in common plus some other bits.

So is there merit to duplicating the columns in all tables or having a common table for this common object.Should all 3 tables have from,to,departure,arrival or is there merit to abstracting that into a trip_details table that then has a from,to,arrival,departure,type. Type would be an enum for search,saved,booked.

I've been asked to provide some sample tables so here they are

Approach 1

```
recent -> id,from,to,departure,return,user_id
saved  -> id,from,to,departure,return,user_id,flight_id
booked -> id,from,to,departure,return,user_id,flight_id,confirmation_number,payment_type... etc
```

Approach 2

```
trip_details -> id,from,to,departure,return,user_id, type(recent,saved,booked)

recent -> id, trip_details_id, user_id
saved  -> id, trip_details_id, user_id, flight_id
booked -> id, trip_details_id, user_id, confirmation_number, payment_type... etc
```

**Note:** 
Trip details row will never be shared across the 3 tables. Approach 2 will not reduce redundant data

**EDIT**
To help clarify, these are not my tables, I'm trying to figure this out in the abstract. Also maybe an example of the programming would help. **Please don't get too hung up on the implementation details as I'm trying to figure out the question "if 3 tables all have 5 columns that are the same type and conceptually represent an object should that 'object' live in its own table? Even if moving it to its own table will not reduce data redundancy?"**

```
var recentSearch = {
    tripDetails: {
        departure_date: '2015-01-05',
        return_date: '2015-01-10',
        from: 'Orlando',
        to: 'Chicago' 
    }
}

var savedSearch = {
    tripDetails: {
        departure_date: '2015-01-05',
        return_date: '2015-01-10',
        from: 'Orlando',
        to: 'Chicago' 
    }
}

var booked = {
    flight_id: 1234,
    confirmation_number: 3456,
    book_date: '2015-12-12'
    tripDetails: {
        departure_date: '2015-01-05',
        return_date: '2015-01-10',
        from: 'Orlando',
        to: 'Chicago' 
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from learning more about [normalized databases](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/database-normalization/info). This is helpful information.

Comment: Well moving them to the trip_details won't help reduce data redundancy since a search can exist with the same details as a saved flight. It seems that normalizing only applies if you are preventing data duplication

Comment: you need only three tables. trips, saved, booked. i don't understand the recent one

Comment: trips will be the all_trips_available, saved is just saved one of the trip without any redundant details. booked will have booking details + trip_id + log of "current trip details that may change over longer periods of time"

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should only have each unit of data represented once in the entire DB, across all tables. If you want a user to book a flight for example, you would use three tables:

User,

Flight,

Booking,

User should contain all data relevant to the user(name, pw, address, etc).

Flight should contain all of the data relevant to the flight(plane, departure time, destination, etc). Each plane journey would have one row in the table to describe it.

Booking would then hold all of your saved flights information with a reference to both of the other tables(So it must contain userId and flightId as foriegn keys but after that you could add additional information if you wish).

The booking table will also double as a saved flights list.

EDIT: To clarify, if you want saved flights that are not booked flights you have two options.
1) Make a separate table for saved flights.
2) Add a column to your Booking/trip table that indicates whether or not the flight is booked or saved.

Personally I would use option 2 unless there is some chance that there will be a huge number of saved searches compared to regular bookings.

EDIT2: You should redesign this DB. You have three tables there, all storing the same information. There is no reason for "recent" and "saved" to be separate tables, or for there to be a "recent" table at all for that matter.

Try to redesign with the above pattern in mind. So each flight should be represented once and only once in your db, each user represented once and only once and then the booked flights would be a table with just the users unique id and the flights unique id.

If you want to save a flight without booking it you can either replicate the book flights table and call it saved flights or just add them to the same table with some attribute that determines if the flight is booked or just saved.

The biggest issue I can see here is that all of your tables contain the attributes(from, to, departure and return). All of these could be held in a single table and tracked here using a single attribute(flight_id).

Even if you want to keep the saved, recent and booked tables separate you could do this. As it stands you have four attributes that appear in three tables, this should only ever be a single attribute if the information is repeated.

Short answer:

Do this:

Flight(id(pk), departureTime, from, to, return)

User(id(pk), name, etc)

Recent(id(pk), User_id(fk), Flight_id(fk))

Booked(id(pk), User_id(fk), Flight(fk), confirmation_no, etc)

This should take care of 99% of your issues. The rest of your functionality you are going to handle by querying the database rather than by the way you lay it out.

Comment: the tables I picked were very important since if you draw a ven diagram of the data in my 3 tables they have an overlapping "trip details" intersection. Your don't have such

Comment: You did not say anything about a ven diagram...

Either way, rename Booking to trip details and you are good to go. Overlapping is not a good thing, you should only have a single value overlapping so that you can join the tables. Anything else would be redundancy and bad design.

Anything that overlaps should be a separate table.

Comment: The data will never overlap, only the data types. So the an initial search would be duplicated as a save so that there is still a recent search and also a saved search, the saved search could potentially be modified thus the data is duplicated.

Comment: can you provide your tables so that the question is not so ambiguous? Also what do you mean by data types being able to overlap? A data type is the format of the data, like varchar or enum, they cant overlap, its one per attribute.

From what you are saying here it looks like you want to save queries, that is something you could do with a table containing 2 attributes, (UserId, QueryText)

Comment: Added some sample data sources to the question

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong direction I think. Try not to think of a booking as a different thing to a trip. They are the same only that one is in the future and one is in the past.

Ideally you would have a table which contains all the details about the plane journey itself regardless of who is on that plane or if anyone is at all. You would also have a table to represent each user, this will be used to separate general information from specific information. Then you link both of these tables with a relational table, this allows you to determine which user is on which flight

Comment: Do this:
Flight(id, departureTime, from, to, return)

User(id, name, etc)

Recent(id(pk), User_id(fk), Flight_id(fk))

Booked(id(pk), User_id(fk), Flight(fk), confirmation_no, etc)

Comment: These tables are an example of the abstract question. Please don't get hung up on the business logic. I have 3 tables that share a common 4 or 5 columns which in the programming end would be loaded into a common model. So the booked, recent, and saved all have a property that is a tripDetails interface. So saved.tripDetails has the 4 pieces of data. Once again these tables are just an example to get at a conceptual question i have.

Comment: Well my answer would be the correct way to do your abstract example database. We can only help you with the information you provide us. Regardless, your question has been answered. You should not have 4 columns repeated across multiple tables, you should have those 4 columns in a separate table and joined by a foreign key to each table you need them in.

Also, you mention that Approach 2 does not reduce redundant data...it in fact does.

Comment: it doesn't because you have a type(recent,saved,booked) column. If you save a search it would be a duplicate of the same date in recent with a different type

Comment: Ok, understand you, but the answer is the same. My examples are me applying the abstract ideal to your example.

For the most recent example you posted you have three elements and each contains a trip data element. That trip data element should be its own table with a unique id. Then you put the id into those other tables to represent those columns. That way you can have the same trip details element in many of your other tables while the actual for the trip details element only exists in one row of your db. 

For a better explanation try:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Yes the general Idea mostly is to reduce Data Redundancy / Duplicate Data as much as possible.

But then there are situations like the one you presented, Let's Summarise that and tell me if I am wrong in interpretation somewhere:

There are three places
1. Trip Details
2. My Saved Flights
3. Booked Flight

Here Trip Details is a Generic Search of trips Available and you have that saved in Table "Trips"

My Saved Flights is an option where the person can save that trip so that they do not have to search.

Till Now Best Method: 
In "My_Saved_Flights" Table save the "trip_ID" from the "Trip" Table with data like "saved_on_date" and "User_ID" 
Now when you will show My Saved Flights you get the trip and it's current price and status using a LEFT JOIN.

Now the Third is Booked Flights

 This is something that goes down as history and so you need to see that normally trip timings do change someday or the other or not? If they do you need to store these details else you can store the ID.

I prefer partial storing i.e. store the things that have even a slightest chance of changing in a single text column like this

```
{departure_location: Orlando,destination_location: Miami,departure_date: 2016-05-05,return_date: 2016-05-10}
```

I hope i am helpful

Comment: so you prefer completely denormalizing the stay details into a json object and storing it in a single column? I'm not sure if i'm following you.

Comment: That shall be the case only and press only for those details that might change ten years so later. or you can create a log file in json format and just store the ID of the log here in DB.

Comment: according to me all the data will come from trip table [on first two tables] using Trip_ID but an yearly/monthly log file will store the json with a generated id for booking table and so the history of booking table will come from logs and not the trip table.

Comment: FYI: whatever i have said is only for overlapping data any data that will be specific to the table like amount,date,time of booking will be in database normally. I guess you get that. Log will only have the minimum possible dynamic data